# How to align text vertically in panel using bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an image and a description of a `panel panel-default`. The image is pulled to the left and the description is on the right side.

The image has the `img-responsive` class so when I resize the window it fits the panel body.

The question is how can I achieve the same effect with the description. I would like to align it vertically to the panel and when I resize the window it should also fit the panel body.

What I have tried so far:

```css
.container {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

p {
  font-size: 2vw;
}

.panel {
  border-radius: 0;
}

.panel-body {
  padding: 0;
}

.panel-description {
  margin-top 12px;
  padding-left: 3px;
}

.vertical-center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.no-padding {
  padding: 0;
}

.no-padding-right {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Basic panel example
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 no-padding-right">
              <div class="panel-image">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" class="img-responsive" alt="img">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 no-padding">
              <div class="panel-description vertical-center">
                <p>Name<br>Surname</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Basic panel example
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I added

```
.vertical-center {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

to the `.panel-description` but it's not working.

What is the best solution for this problem?

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/39282/

Comment: For text you can always use media queries or percentages to make it responsive, as for panel description the problem is your HTML structure.

Comment: what is wrong with the structure ?

Comment: You need to put flex in the div that contains all the elements you want to position.

Comment: i puted it to the description div because this is the element i would like to center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made little change in your code and its working well now. Here is the updated code for your reference

```css
.container {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

p {
  font-size: 2vw;
}

.panel {
  border-radius: 0;
}

.panel-body {
  padding: 0;
}

.panel-description {
  margin-top 12px;
  padding-left: 3px;
}

.no-padding-right {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.main-class {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Basic panel example
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="main-class">
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 no-padding-right">
                  <div class="panel-image">
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" class="img-responsive" alt="img">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 no-padding">
                  <div class="panel-description vertical-center">
                    <p>Name<br>Surname</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Basic panel example
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```